# Android Studio jumping over breakpoints

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am running into an issue where Android Studio is jumping over my breakpoint. I haven't run into this issue before and this recently started happening.

I am running Android Studio 2.3.1 on a MAC with no exotic plugins. Any ideas? Here is the code:

```
private fun getLatestZip(): File? {
        var fileName = context.fileList().find { it.toUpperCase().contains("MBTA_GTFS") }
        var dateTime = getGftsTimestamp()
        var file: File?
        if (dateTime == null) {
            file = downloadLatestGfts() // skips the break on this line
            if (file != null) {
                printGftsTimestamp()
            }
            else {
                Timber.e("Failed to download Gfts") // and goes straight to here
            }
        } else if (!fileName.isNullOrEmpty()) {....
```

EDIT ---
Here's a video to show you exactly what's happening. It could be a problem with kotlin. https://youtu.be/fJOIzD8ckv8

Comment: Looks rather like a mismatch between the source and the compiled code. 
 You might try renaming your top level and app build folders to build.old to force a rebuild of everything.   I find this helps when studio gets confused (or I do).

Answer (score 0):

You need to place breakpoint in downloadLatestGfts() function or press F8 to go to next line (i.e file null check if statement).

Comment: I am pressing f8 to step over the function. I even put breakpoints within the `downloadLatestGfts()` funciton.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the code putting a breakpoint on the line

```
if (dateTime == null)
```

and check whether the value of dateTime is null. It may be because of that null value the control goes straight to else condition.